# How to setup apache server to run legacy PHP application (PHP 5.4.45) in docker?

Tags: php, mysql, docker

I am trying to build three containers (`mysql`, `phpmyadmin`, and `php-env`) with this docker-compose setup:

```
version: '3.1'

services:
  php-env:
    build: .
    platform: linux/amd64
    volumes:
      - "/opt/homebrew/var/www/:/var/www/html"
    ports:
      - "9000:8080"

  db:
    image: mysql
    restart: always
    platform: linux/amd64
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_DATABASE: test_db
    ports:
      - "3308:3306"
      
  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin:latest
    restart: always
    platform: linux/amd64
    environment:
      PMA_HOST: db
      PMA_USER: root
      PMA_PASSWORD: root
    ports:
      - "9001:80"
```

I use this dockerfile for the build:

```
FROM --platform=linux/amd64 php:5.4-apache

WORKDIR /var/www/html

RUN echo "ServerName localhost" >> /etc/apache2/apache2.conf

RUN docker-php-ext-install MySQL
```

The `db` and `mysql` container work properly, but the php-env doesn't (the `phpmyadmin` and `db` which are in port 3308 and 9001 can be exposed from my local), but the `php-env` container that is exposed in port 9000 doesn't work (when I input `localhost:9000`) it yields error page `The connection was reset. The connection to the server was reset while the page was loading.`

So I think the Apache is not being run properly in the `php-env` container, so from Docker Desktop, in the `php-env` container terminal, I execute commands `# /etc/init.d/apache2 start` which yields this message `[ ok ] Starting web server: apache2.` that shows the Apache server is being started.

But when I try to access it from my local `localhost:9000` the problem `The connection was reset ...` still arises. How to fix the situation so that I can properly run a PHP application that is exposed in port 9000 in my local (outside container)?

---

I don't know if it will be relevant, but here are some additional informations:

1. When I build using `docker-compose up --build`, here is the snippet of the build message:

   ```
    www-php-env-1     | [Tue Jul 18 03:03:42.075140 2023] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 1] AH00163: Apache/2.4.10 (Debian) PHP/5.4.45 configured -- resuming normal operations
    www-php-env-1     | [Tue Jul 18 03:03:42.077266 2023] [core:notice] [pid 1] AH00094: Command line: 'apache2 -D FOREGROUND'
   ```
2. I am using MacOS Ventura with M1 Chip and have defined the platform `linux/amd64` for the container (as I mentioned in the setup).
3. I have arbitrarily changed the port `"9000:8080"` in the `php-env` setup but the problem is still there. So I think it is not a problem of port allocation.

---

UPDATES:

1. In my `/etc/apache2/ports.conf`, the apache listen on port `80`

   ```
    # cat /etc/apache2/ports.conf
    # If you just change the port or add more ports here, you will likely also
    # have to change the VirtualHost statement in
    # /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf

    Listen 80

    <IfModule ssl_module>
            Listen 443
    </IfModule>

    <IfModule mod_gnutls.c>
            Listen 443
    </IfModule>
   ```

Comment: On which port is the Apache HTTP server listening? What is/are the port/s in your Apache configuration? Make this part of your configuration visible in your question by [edit]ing it.

Comment: In my `/etc/apache2/ports.conf` it listen on port `80`

Comment: So why do you then bind port 9000 to 8080 and not 9000 to 80 if I may ask?

Comment: And the _"The connection was reset. The connection to the server was reset while the page was loading."_ error in an Apache PHP 5.4 setup can be a sign that PHP crashed. Check the error log for more information, can be a syntax error or similar. The connection is closed too early then.

Comment: @hakre _"Connection reset"_ is simply the message you receive when Docker tries to port forward to an unbound port. The **very** simple solution to this is to use port binding `"9000:80"`

Comment: @Phil Yes, already commented on the port setting, but also found the question not clear at that point like as if `9000:80` could have been used before it was changed to `9000:8080` and older PHP versions also have that other error picture. Anyway, unless the OP does not react to all the comments, there is little to go on with this guesswork.